# EDITING an Image link in Sharpoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am having difficulty finding documentation for "editing" not adding an image link. There is plenty of documentation on adding and creating but nothing on "changing" the hyperlink. At least not that I have found. Does anyone have any info on it?

Comment: where is the image link?

Comment: on the main site page. it takes you to a subsite that's a sharepoint list.

Comment: add print screen!!

Comment: Don't' have an image insertion button for some reason on here. However to give you a clear understanding of where I am, I am in the edit design web part on the site page. That web part contains the images that are linked.

Comment: What is the "edit design web part"? A content editor web part? I suggest you provide more information for further research. If you can't upload the screenshots in the reply, you can upload the images to OneDrive and share the link in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an embedded image in a web page, and that image is also a hyperlink?

If that's the case, go to the page in question and click Edit (top, right hand corner). You have two options from there. I personally prefer option 2.

1) click once on the image you care about, and then click the Link ribbon (green color). You'll see the hyperlink under that image in the URL field, where you can edit it. Click Save (top, right hand corner) when you're done.

2) Highlight-select the image you care about, and then select Edit Source from the Format Text ribbon, this will bring up the underlying HTML, and you can modify the  tag directly, and also make sure that the bracketing around the image is what you want it to be.

Good luck.

Comment: The issue I am having is with your 1). Even in Edit mode clicking on it, normally or lightly, it always redirects away from the page I am editing me to where the link is. It's extremely frustrating.

Comment: ...so essentially I never get to the "click the link ribbon(green color)" part.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in sharepoint designer?

Comment: That's why I like the #2 option better - you can start your highlight a few characters to one side, and keep going to the other side - you never have to click on the link.

Comment: If you want to go #1, you can put your cursor nearby and then arrow-key over until you're "on" the image - that sometimes works. But generally speaking, it's just faster to edit the source directly.

Comment: You can edit the page in SPD: edit page (open the page from the SitePages list), but that's not terribly different from #2, just takes more clicks to open SPD.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply delete the image by highlighting it and hitting delete on the keyboard? This will stop it from triggering the hyperlink and you can just re add with the correct link?